# psfragify? Aka problem with EPS and pdfLaTeX

Tags: graphics, pdftex, psfrag, epstopdf

If I want to include a `.eps` image and yet use pdfLaTeX, I can do so using `epstopdf` (manually called, automated in TL2010+, using the package). However, as far as I know, all these options are incompatible with `psfrag`.

I would be interested in a utility, let's say `psfragify`, that would take a LaTeX source code, extract all `.eps` graphics that use `\psfrag` directives, and run `latex+dvips`(`+ps2pdf`) on them, to obtain corrected graphics that can be used in pdfLaTeX. Of course, this should solve the problem of using the correct fonts, too.

(If no such utility exists, I'm probably going to make one, but I would like to know whether the work has not been done before.)

Comment: Have you tried `pstool`?

Comment: @Joseph not really, I'll look into it, but it looks promising on the first sight ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a perl script called [unpsfrag](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2002-November/003325.html) that does exactly what you need. I used to use it many years ago; I'm not sure how well it will work with newer packages.